# Swift GET request with Authentication

Tags: json, swift, rest

So I'm new to Swift/SwiftUI but I'm trying to use REST API to get a list of job submitted but I can't figure out why its not working, I've definitely got something wrong but have no idea what it is

UPDATED CODE 01-05-2023

```
//
//  Dev_GetJobList.swift
//  Dynamo
//
//  Created by Matthew Badsey on 29/04/2023.
//
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct DEV_GetJobList: View {
    
    @State var jobs = [Job]()
    @AppStorage("access_token") var TokenCheck: String = "None"
    @AppStorage("isMember") var MemberCheck: String = "None"
    
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var alertMessage = ""

    var body: some View {
            List(jobs) { job in
                NavigationLink(destination: JobDetailView(job: job)) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(job.jobAddr1 )
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(job.jobAgentNotes ?? "")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Text(job.jobContractorNotes ?? "")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Job Listings")
        
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.badsey.app/\(MemberCheck)/API/dp_jobs/read.php?pageno=1&pagesize=1") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(TokenCheck)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            print("---> data: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")
            do {
                let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(JobAPI.self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.jobs = decodedResponse.document.records
                    }
               } catch {
                 print(error)
             }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct JobAPI: Codable {
     let status: String
     let code: Int
     let message: String
     let document: JobRecords
 }

 struct JobRecords: Codable {
     let pageno, pagesize, totalCount: String
     let records: [Job]

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case pageno, pagesize, records
         case totalCount = "total_count"
     }
 }
 
 struct Job: Codable, Identifiable {
        let id: Int
        let jobUniqid: String
        let jobClientJobNo: String?
        let jobPriority: String?
        let jobQuoteNo: String?
        let jobInvoiceNo: String?
        let jobStatus: Int
        let jobAgentId: Int
        let jobAddr1: String
        let jobAddr2: String?
        let jobTownCity: String?
        let jobCounty: String
        let jobPostcode: String
        let jobContactName1: String?
        let jobContactNo1: String?
        let jobContactEmail1: String?
        let jobContactName2: String?
        let jobContactNo2: String?
        let jobContactEmail2: String?
        let jobSentBy: String?
        let jobType: Int
        let jobContractorId: Int
        let jobDescription: String?
        let jobDescriptionShort: String?
        let jobBudget: String?
        let jobContractorBudget: String?
        let jobCreatedDate: String?
        let jobAgentNotes: String?
        let jobContractorNotes: String?
        let job_dynamo_notes : String?
        let job_notes : String?
        let job_contractor_instructed : Date
        let job_contractor_action : String?
        let job_contractor_accepted : Date
        let job_contractor_accepted_date : Date
        let job_contractor_description : String?
        let job_contractor_price_agreed : String?
        let job_booked_date : Date
        let job_quoted_date : Date
        let job_accepted_date : Date
        let job_start_date : Date
        let job_completion_date : Date
        let job_invoice_date : Date
        let job_onhold_date : Date
        let job_cancelled_date : Date
        let job_total_quote : Date
        let job_contractor_cut_pre_vat : String?
        let job_contractor_cut : String?
        let job_dynamo_cut : String?
        let job_agents_cut : String?
        let job_sophie_cut : String?
        let job_invoice_amount : String?
        let job_pre_vat_amount : String?
        let job_net_amount : String?
        let job_vat_amount : String?
        let job_gsc_expiry_date : Date
        let job_floor_plan : String?
        let job_vat_charged : String?
        let job_vat_collected : String?
        let job_invoice_notes : String?
        let job_contractor_paid : String?
        let job_invoice_paid : String?
        let job_invoice_paid_email : String?
        let job_agents_vat : String?
        let job_vat_liability : String?
        let job_contractor_invoice : String?
        let job_contractor_invoice_no : String?
        let job_contact_reason : String?
        let job_quote_description : String?
        let job_contractor_proceed : Date?
        let job_contractor_proceed_receipt : String?
        let job_send_sms : Int?
        let job_details_of_gsc : String?
        let job_details_id : Int?
        let job_introducer_id : Int?
        let job_introducer_commission_paid : Date?
        let job_eicr_expiry_date : Date?
        let job_eicr_expiry_info : Date?
        let job_epc_expiry_info : Date?
        let job_gsc_expiry_info : Date?
        let job_epc_expiry_date : Date?
        let job_onhold_reason : String?
        let job_part_payment_received : String?
        let job_contractor_part_payment_paid : String?
        let job_contractor_balance : String?
        let job_quote_rejected_date : Date?
        let job_reminder_sent : Data?
        let job_deposit_invoiced : String?
        let job_amber_list : String?
 }

struct JobDetailView: View {
    
    let job: Job
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(job.jobAddr1)
                .font(.headline)
            Text(job.jobAgentNotes ?? "")
                .font(.subheadline)
            Text(job.jobContractorNotes ?? "")
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(job.jobAddr1 )
    }
}

struct DEV_GetJobList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DEV_GetJobList()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get JSON data to output in a NavigationLink, I've tried searching for an answer before posting this

UPDATE: JSON Response

```
{
"status": "success",
"code": 1,
"message": "dp_jobs found",
"document": {
    "pageno": "1",
    "pagesize": "1",
    "total_count": "36033",
    "records": [
        {
            "ID": "013",
            "job_uniqid": "",
            "job_client_job_no": "",
            "job_priority": "",
            "job_quote_no": "",
            "job_invoice_no": "-",
            "job_status": "5",
            "job_agent_id": "18",
            "job_addr_1": "",
            "job_addr_2": "",
            "job_town_city": "",
            "job_county": "",
            "job_postcode": "",
            "job_contact_name_1": "",
            "job_contact_no_1": "",
            "job_contact_email_1": "",
            "job_contact_name_2": "",
            "job_contact_no_2": "",
            "job_contact_email_2": "",
            "job_sent_by": "",
            "job_type": null,
            "job_contractor_id": "",
            "job_description": "",
            "job_description_short": "",
            "job_budget": "",
            "job_contractor_budget": "",
            "job_created_date": "",
            "job_agent_notes": null,
            "job_contractor_notes": null,
            "job_dynamo_notes": "",
            "job_notes": "",
            "job_contractor_instructed": null,
            "job_contractor_action": "",
            "job_contractor_accepted": null,
            "job_contractor_accepted_date": null,
            "job_contractor_description": null,
            "job_contractor_price_agreed": "",
            "job_booked_date": "2017-10-27",
            "job_quoted_date": "2017-10-20",
            "job_accepted_date": null,
            "job_start_date": null,
            "job_completion_date": "2017-10-27",
            "job_invoice_date": "2017-10-27",
            "job_onhold_date": null,
            "job_cancelled_date": null,
            "job_total_quote": "",
            "job_contractor_cut_pre_vat": "",
            "job_contractor_cut": "115",
            "job_dynamo_cut": "",
            "job_agents_cut": "",
            "job_sophie_cut": null,
            "job_invoice_amount": "",
            "job_pre_vat_amount": "",
            "job_net_amount": "",
            "job_vat_amount": "",
            "job_gsc_expiry_date": null,
            "job_floor_plan": null,
            "job_vat_charged": "",
            "job_vat_collected": "",
            "job_invoice_notes": "-",
            "job_contractor_paid": null,
            "job_invoice_paid": null,
            "job_invoice_paid_email": null,
            "job_agents_vat": null,
            "job_vat_liability": null,
            "job_contractor_invoice": null,
            "job_contractor_invoice_no": null,
            "job_contact_reason": null,
            "job_quote_description": "",
            "job_contractor_proceed": null,
            "job_contractor_proceed_receipt": null,
            "job_send_sms": null,
            "job_details_of_gsc": "",
            "job_details_id": null,
            "job_introducer_id": null,
            "job_introducer_commission_paid": null,
            "job_eicr_expiry_date": null,
            "job_eicr_expiry_info": "",
            "job_epc_expiry_info": "",
            "job_gsc_expiry_info": "",
            "job_epc_expiry_date": null,
            "job_onhold_reason": "",
            "job_part_payment_received": "",
            "job_contractor_part_payment_paid": "-",
            "job_contractor_balance": "",
            "job_quote_rejected_date": null,
            "job_reminder_sent": null,
            "job_deposit_invoiced": "",
            "job_amber_list": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Define not working? What's happening? What's the values of the print? Is `decodedResponse` not nil? You use `try` when it's recommended to use a `do`/`try`/`catch` and not ignore the errors.

Comment: Sorry it's not very clear @Larme
print("Error \(String(describing: error))") shows as nil
and 
print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")") shows an unknown error

Comment: `try? JSONDecoder()` fails then because there is a return. Use `try!` instead of `try?` (it will crash, but error should appear in Console), or use a `do`/`try`/`catch` and print the error thrown. Read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/errorhandling/

Comment: Your JSON is not a `[String: JobResponse]`, it's a `[String: Any]` where ONE of its key-value is a `String`-`JobResponse`, that's why the decoding is failing.

Comment: As mentioned, use `do/try/catch` around your `...try JSONDecoder()...` instead of the `try? JSONDecoder...` and put
 `print(error)` in the catch, you will soon see where your errors are.
 Note, it is easier to just copy and paste your json data into https://app.quicktype.io/
  it will generate the models for you, or you can do it by hand and get errors.
 Note also, you should not use `@AppStorage` for storing your secret keys, use keychain.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I don't plan on doing the final release if AppStorage, just for my testing and learning.

I now have an error message that says `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to parse empty data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to parse empty data.})))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not decoding the json data into **matching** struct models. That is why you get some errors.

Try this example code, works for me in my test.

You still need to consult the API docs to determine which properties are optional.

In `func loadData()`

```
 do {
    let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(JobAPI.self, from: data) // <-- here
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.jobs = decodedResponse.document.records // <-- here
        }
   } catch {
     print(error)  // <--- important
 }
```

Models:

```
 struct JobAPI: Codable {
     let status: String
     let code: Int
     let message: String
     let document: JobRecords
 }

 struct JobRecords: Codable {
     let pageno, pagesize, totalCount: String
     let records: [Job]

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case pageno, pagesize, records
         case totalCount = "total_count"
     }
 }
   
struct Job: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String   // <-- here
    let jobUniqid: String
    let jobClientJobNo: String
    let jobPriority: String
    let jobQuoteNo: String
    let jobInvoiceNo: String
    let jobStatus: String
    let jobAgentId: String
    let jobAddr1: String
    let jobAddr2: String
    let jobTownCity: String
    let jobCounty: String?
    let jobPostcode: String
    let jobContactName1: String
    let jobContactNo1: String
    let jobContactEmail1: String
    let jobContactName2: String
    let jobContactNo2: String
    let jobContactEmail2: String
    let jobSentBy: String
    let jobType: String?
    let jobContractorId: String
    let jobDescription: String
    let jobDescriptionShort: String
    let jobBudget: String
    let jobContractorBudget: String
    let jobCreatedDate: String
    let jobAgentNotes: String?  // <-- here
    let jobContractorNotes: String?  // <-- here
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case jobUniqid = "job_uniqid"
        case jobClientJobNo = "job_client_job_no"
        case jobPriority = "job_priority"
        case jobQuoteNo = "job_quote_no"
        case jobInvoiceNo = "job_invoice_no"
        case jobStatus = "job_status"
        case jobAgentId = "job_agent_id"
        case jobAddr1 = "job_addr_1"
        case jobAddr2 = "job_addr_2"
        case jobTownCity = "job_town_city"
        case jobCounty = "job_county"
        case jobPostcode = "job_postcode"
        case jobContactName1 = "job_contact_name_1"
        case jobContactNo1 = "job_contact_no_1"
        case jobContactEmail1 = "job_contact_email_1"
        case jobContactName2 = "job_contact_name_2"
        case jobContactNo2 = "job_contact_no_2"
        case jobContactEmail2 = "job_contact_email_2"
        case jobSentBy = "job_sent_by"
        case jobType = "job_type"
        case jobContractorId = "job_contractor_id"
        case jobDescription = "job_description"
        case jobDescriptionShort = "job_description_short"
        case jobBudget = "job_budget"
        case jobContractorBudget = "job_contractor_budget"
        case jobCreatedDate = "job_created_date"
        case jobAgentNotes = "job_agent_notes"
        case jobContractorNotes = "job_contractor_notes"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's now outputting an error message of the following `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to parse empty data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to parse empty data.})))`

Comment: add this `print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")` before the `do{...}` and show us what it prints. I suspect the json data you show is not what you get from the server.

Comment: So just looking at URL at it wasn't the URL I was after, however the structure is still the same, but for some reason wasn't showing data, after updating it I'm now seeing the JSON Data, but get this error mssg

`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "document", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "records", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: can you show exactly what you get from `print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")` , that is, the real json data you get from the server. It looks like the `id` in the `Job` struct should be optional, or should not be there.

Comment: Yeh sure, here's the link [link](https://snippet.host/oaawck)

Comment: very strange, I can easily decode the data you show with the code in my answer.

Comment: can you update your question and show the code for `func loadData(){...}`

Comment: yeh sure, just done it now!

Comment: updated my answer with the `struct Job` that decodes your json data. You must include the `enum CodingKeys` and have `let id: String`

Comment: Thank you so much, I had to make everything expect id and jobUniqid to optional but it seems to all work! I really appreciate it!